# What is the meaning of ATS_EXTERN_PREFIX?

Tags: ats

For instance, I saw the following line in ATSLIB:

```
#define ATS_EXTERN_PREFIX "atslib_"
```

What is the meaning of ATS_EXTERN_PREFIX? what is its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If we have `#define ATS_EXTERN_PREFIX "FOO_"` and `extern fun bar (...): ... = "mac#%"`, then the external name of `bar` becomes `${ATS_EXTERN_PREFIX}bar`, i.e. `FOO_bar`.

Essentially, the '%' in the declaration is being replaced with the value of `ATS_EXTERN_PREFIX`.